# Position player hand

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, trigonometry, angle

I am making a 2d game and want to position the players hand to where they are pointing. Now an easy way to do this is by moving to the players position using ctx.move(), rotating to point to the mouse using ctx.rotate() and Math.atan2() relative to the players position and drawing the hand. The problem is, I want the hand to offset. Below is what I am trying to achieve.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hh44.png)

Answer (score 0):

Look under `// magic except end load under here`. Library is above that. It was actually somehow difficult to find anything like this example online:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, beacon, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC, shuffle, rand; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, func, responseType = 'json', context = null)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url); x.responseType = responseType;
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(func)func.call(c, x.response);
  }
  x.onerror = e=>{
    if(func)func.call(c, {xhrErrorEvent:e});
  }
  x.send();
  return x;
}
post = function(url, send, func, responseType ='json', context = null){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    const c = context || x;
    x.open('POST', url); x.responseType = responseType;
    x.onload = ()=>{
      if(func)func.call(c, x.response);
    }
    x.onerror = e=>{
      if(func)func.call(c, {xhrErrorEvent:e});
    }
    let d;
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      d = send;
    }
    else{
      let s;
      d = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        s = send[k];
        if(typeof s === 'object' && s)s = JSON.stringify(s);
        d.append(k, s);
      }
    }
    x.send(d);
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
beacon = function(url, send){
  let r = false;
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    let d;
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      d = send;
    }
    else{
      let s;
      d = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        s = send[k];
        if(typeof s === 'object' && s)s = JSON.stringify(s);
        d.append(k, s);
      }
    }
    r = nav.sendBeacon(url, d);
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return r;
}
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = function(node, className){
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
shuffle = array=>{
  let a = array.slice(), i = a.length, n, h;
  while(i){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--); h = a[i]; a[i] = a[n]; a[n] = h;
  }
  return a;
}
rand = (min, max)=>{
  let mn = min, mx = max;
  if(mx === undefined){
    mx = mn; mn = 0;
  }
  return mn+Math.floor(Math.random()*(mx-mn+1));
}
// magic except end load under here 
const canvas = I('canvas');
let cb = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), cX, cY, af = true, action = false;
canvas.width = cb.width; canvas.height = cb.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';

function createRect(){
  ctx.rect(cX-2, cY-37, 4, 37);
  ctx.stroke(); ctx.fill();
}
function noAct(){
  action = false;
}
function moveit(e, hit = false){
  af = true; cb = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  let w = cb.width, h = cb.height, p = 180/Math.PI, r;
  ctx.save(); ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h); ctx.beginPath(); ctx.translate(cX, cY);
  r = hit ? 0 : 90;
  ctx.rotate((p*Math.atan2(e.clientY-cb.top-cY, e.clientX-cb.left-cX)+r)/p);
  ctx.translate(-cX, -cY); createRect(e); ctx.restore();
}
function movement(e, hit = false){
  if(af && action){
    af = false; 
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{ 
      moveit(e, hit);
    });
  }
}
function act(e){
  action = true; cX = e.clientX-cb.left; cY = e.clientY-cb.top; movement(e, true);
}
if(mobile){
  canvas.ontouchstart = e=>{
    act(e.touches[0]);
  }
  touchmove = e=>{
    movement(e.touches[0]);
  }
  ontouchend = noAct;
}
else{
  canvas.onmousedown = act; onmousemove = movement; onmouseup = noAct;
}
}); // end load
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; font:22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
.main{
  background:#aaa; padding:10px; overflow-y:auto;
}
#canvas{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have no clue what is going on in the code! The example shows what I am already able to do: point the player to the mouse. What I need is the hand to be offset. In front of the player, on the left side. This means the player angle will be different than the hand angle.

Comment: If you get rid of the mousedown then `cX` and `cY` can be placed at any coordinates.

Comment: I need to calculate the x and y position of the hand relative to the players position and rotation. If the player is facing right, the hand will be to the top left corner of the "square" that the players circle is in.

Comment: Did you click the mouse and move it around? The red line points to where the mouse is. You should be able to figure it out with what's been given.